# Unable to build and run docker containers using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file to build and run nodejs web app along with MongoDB instance.

When I am running the `docker-compose up --build` the command fails with the below error.

```
Digest: sha256:3a09cd85fb4e76f1d5832f9ea1d4e7481f76e807389b7d8ea6ac4d4ba96f83e5
Status: Downloaded newer image for mongo:latest
Starting db
Recreating compose_web_1

ERROR: for web  no such image: sha256:1fb4f8e17b47e1fafd29d0f425bf86b934130847ff4b99b055c6757ccaad5bc4: No such image: sha256:1fb4f8e17b47e1fafd29d0f425bf86b934130847ff4b99b055c6757ccaad5bc4
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Steps tried:

- Cleaned up all the images.
- Cleaned all the containers running.
- Initially, I was running `docker-compose up` but after the error, I am running `docker-compose up --build`

What could be the potential reason for this error.

docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '2'
    services:
      db:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: db
        networks:
          - todonet
      web:
        build: ../.
        networks:
          - todonet
        ports:
         - "3000"
    networks:
      todonet:
        driver: bridge
```

Directory structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── accepts
│   │   ├── async
│   │   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── basic-auth
│   │   ├── bluebird
│   │   │   └── js
│   │   │       ├── browser
│   │   │       └── main
│   │   ├── body-parser
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │       └── types
│   │   ├── bson
│   │   │   ├── alternate_parsers
│   │   │   ├── browser_build
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   └── bson
│   │   │   │       └── parser
│   │   │   └── tools
│   │   ├── bytes
│   │   ├── cookie
│   │   ├── cookie-parser
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── cookie-signature
│   │   ├── core-util-is
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── crc
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── debug
│   │   ├── depd
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │       └── compat
│   │   ├── destroy
│   │   ├── ee-first
│   │   ├── ejs
│   │   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── support
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   │       └── fixtures
│   │   │           └── includes
│   │   │               └── menu
│   │   ├── ejs-locals
│   │   │   ├── example
│   │   │   │   └── views
│   │   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   │   └── ejs
│   │   │   │       ├── examples
│   │   │   │       ├── lib
│   │   │   │       ├── support
│   │   │   │       └── test
│   │   │   │           └── fixtures
│   │   │   │               └── includes
│   │   │   │                   └── menu
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   │       ├── fixtures
│   │   │       │   ├── blog
│   │   │       │   │   └── post
│   │   │       │   ├── path
│   │   │       │   │   └── to
│   │   │       │   ├── subfolder
│   │   │       │   └── thing
│   │   │       └── support
│   │   ├── errorhandler
│   │   │   └── public
│   │   ├── es6-promise
│   │   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │       └── es6-promise
│   │   │           └── promise
│   │   ├── escape-html
│   │   ├── etag
│   │   ├── express
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   ├── middleware
│   │   │   │   └── router
│   │   │   └── node_modules
│   │   │       └── depd
│   │   │           └── lib
│   │   │               └── compat
│   │   ├── finalhandler
│   │   ├── forwarded
│   │   ├── fresh
│   │   ├── hooks-fixed
│   │   ├── iconv-lite
│   │   │   ├── encodings
│   │   │   │   └── tables
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── inherits
│   │   ├── ipaddr.js
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── isarray
│   │   │   └── build
│   │   ├── kareem
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── media-typer
│   │   ├── merge-descriptors
│   │   ├── method-override
│   │   ├── methods
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── mime
│   │   │   └── types
│   │   ├── mime-db
│   │   ├── mime-types
│   │   ├── mongodb
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │       ├── bulk
│   │   │       ├── gridfs
│   │   │       └── gridfs-stream
│   │   ├── mongodb-core
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │       ├── auth
│   │   │       ├── connection
│   │   │       ├── tools
│   │   │       ├── topologies
│   │   │       │   └── strategies
│   │   │       └── wireprotocol
│   │   ├── mongoose
│   │   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   │   ├── aggregate
│   │   │   │   ├── express
│   │   │   │   │   └── connection-sharing
│   │   │   │   ├── geospatial
│   │   │   │   ├── globalschemas
│   │   │   │   ├── lean
│   │   │   │   ├── mapreduce
│   │   │   │   ├── population
│   │   │   │   ├── promises
│   │   │   │   ├── querybuilder
│   │   │   │   ├── replicasets
│   │   │   │   ├── schema
│   │   │   │   │   └── storing-schemas-as-json
│   │   │   │   └── statics
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   ├── drivers
│   │   │   │   │   ├── browser
│   │   │   │   │   └── node-mongodb-native
│   │   │   │   ├── error
│   │   │   │   ├── schema
│   │   │   │   │   └── operators
│   │   │   │   ├── services
│   │   │   │   └── types
│   │   │   └── node_modules
│   │   │       └── ms
│   │   ├── morgan
│   │   │   └── node_modules
│   │   │       └── depd
│   │   │           └── lib
│   │   │               └── compat
│   │   ├── mpath
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── mpromise
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── mquery
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   └── collection
│   │   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   │   ├── debug
│   │   │   │   ├── ms
│   │   │   │   └── sliced
│   │   │   │       ├── lib
│   │   │   │       └── test
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   │       └── collection
│   │   ├── ms
│   │   ├── muri
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── negotiator
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── on-finished
│   │   ├── parseurl
│   │   ├── path-to-regexp
│   │   ├── proxy-addr
│   │   ├── qs
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── range-parser
│   │   ├── raw-body
│   │   ├── readable-stream
│   │   │   └── lib
│   │   ├── regexp-clone
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── require_optional
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── resolve-from
│   │   ├── semver
│   │   │   ├── bin
│   │   │   └── test
│   │   ├── send
│   │   │   └── node_modules
│   │   │       └── depd
│   │   │           └── lib
│   │   │               └── compat
│   │   ├── serve-favicon
│   │   ├── serve-static
│   │   ├── sliced
│   │   ├── string_decoder
│   │   ├── type-is
│   │   ├── utils-merge
│   │   └── vary
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   ├── routes
│   └── views
├── compose
└── kubernetes
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim
LABEL maintainer = "phanikumaryadavilli@gmail.com"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./app/ ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: It seems like you are specifying a build path which is one level above the directory in which your compose file is in. Can you post the Dockerfile that you have?

Comment: @JayLim I am executing the command from the directory in which I have the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @JayLim added dockerfile.